# How to manipulate style tag in SVG

Tags: javascript, css, stylesheet

I want to remove some rules from style tag using Javascript.
eg:

```
<style>

    @font-face { font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;src:url(&quot;#FontID1&quot;) format(svg)}
    @font-face { font-family:&quot;Nyala&quot;;src:url(&quot;#FontID0&quot;) format(svg)}
    .fil2 {fill:#05BAE4}
    .fil3 {fill:#373435}
    .fil1 {fill:#05BAE4;fill-rule:nonzero}
    .fil0 {fill:#11D6CC;fill-rule:nonzero}
    .fnt1 {font-weight:normal;font-size:189.311;font-family:'Arial'}
    .fnt0 {font-weight:normal;font-size:615.094;font-family:'Nyala'}

  </style>
```

I want to remove  the @font-face rules and replace it with something else.
Can anybody tell me how it is done?

Comment: Replace it with what?

Comment: You could just append new `@font-face` rules and let cascading (the "C" in "CSS") do its job...

Comment: With another css rule like @font-face { font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;src:url("a.ttf")

Comment: @Boldewyn hmm, let me try that

Comment: You can start from this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/boldewyn/eywyx6g3/

Comment: @Boldewyn Ya it is working. There was some other mistake. The suggestion made by you was correct

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding this:

```
<script type="text/plain" id="allFonts">
<style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
        font-family: MuseoSlab;
        src: url('/fonts/Museo_Slab.otf');
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: MuseoSans;
        src: url('/fonts/MuseoSans.otf');
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: Neuton;
        src: url('/fonts/Neuton.otf');
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: Stag-Medium;
        src: url('/fonts/STAG-MEDIUM_0.otf');
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: STAGSANS;
        src: url('/fonts/STAGSANS-MEDIUM_0.otf');
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: Zapf;
        src: url('/fonts/Zapf.otf');
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: GLSNECB;
        src: url('/fonts/GLSNECB.otf');
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: HELVETIA;
        src: url('/fonts/HELVETIA.otf');
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: "CG Omega";
        src: url('/fonts/STAG-MEDIUM_0.otf');
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: "Eurostile LT Bold";
        src: url('/fonts/STAGSANS-MEDIUM_0.otf');
    }
</style>
</script>
```

and in script:

```
            $("style").after($("#allFonts").text());
```

and it was working..

Comment: The `font-family` names of the new `@font-face` declarations must match "Arial" and "Nyala", if you want them to change. You could just take, say, `/fonts/HELVETICA.otf` and declare it with `font-family:Arial;`.

Comment: Ya. I was testing with these fonts also. still didn't work. I also tested directly without script. still not working

Comment: also I am appending to an SVG document